What's the most efficient way to map a large number of values to a large number of intervals?
I have a vector with many (let's say millions of) values between 0 and K, and a data frame of non-overlapping intervals ('start' and 'end'). What's the most time- and memory-efficient way to map every value to an interval? A straightforward approach is of course to use sapply, but this is very time consuming.
I figured I could perhaps more cleverly use matrix operations to do this faster, e.g.:
lessThanEnd <= values %*% t(1/intervals$end) < 1 
greaterThanStart <= values %*% t(1/intervals$start) > 1
withinInterval <- (lessThanEnd)*(greaterThanStart)

To get a matrix indicating for each point whether it's within each interval. But with a large number of points and intervals these matrices get very large or even exceed the memory limit.
Is there a faster, less memory-taxing way to do this that's not occurring to me? It's possible a package like GenomicRanges already has a function to do this that I'm not aware of? Thanks.

Have you tried the base function findInterval()? It's implemented in C (source here) so should be fairly fast.

Yes that's much faster, thanks!

Let's compare the speed of the matrix multiplication approach to the base function findInterval(). I'll use a numeric vector of length 10,000:
# Approach in the question
get_interval <- function(values, breaks) {
    intervals <- data.frame(start = breaks, end = c(breaks[-1], Inf))
    lessThanEnd <- values %*% t(1 / intervals$end) < 1
    greaterThanStart <- values %*% t(1 / intervals$start) > 1
    withinInterval <- ((lessThanEnd) * (greaterThanStart))

    # We have to add this to turn the large matrix produced
    # into a vector of matchiing intervals
    whichInterval <- which(
        withinInterval == 1,
        arr.ind = TRUE
    )
    whichInterval[, 2][order(whichInterval[, 1])]
}

bench::mark(
    relative = TRUE,
    get_interval(values, breaks),
    findInterval(values, breaks)
)

Results:
# A tibble: 2 × 9
  expression                     min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>                   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 get_interval(values, breaks) 3573.  3071.        1      4288.     2.59     2     7      676ms
2 findInterval(values, breaks)    1      1      2557.        1      1     3779     2      500ms

So findInterval() is about 3000 times faster.
Incidentally, your approach only works if all values positive. This may not be a problem in your case.
Data
set.seed(100)
N <- 1e4
# Add constant so all positive
# (not required for findInterval but is for matrix method)
values <- rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1000) + 5e3
breaks <- 0:(N * 10)

